# Python asyncio: return vs set_result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Hello asyncio experts,

How to correctly return results from a coroutine? Do I need to use return or future.set_result?

For example:

```
@coroutine
def do_something()
    result = yield from some_function()
    return result
```

Or

```
@coroutine
def do_something()
    future = asyncio.Future()
    result = yield from some_function()
    future.set_result(result)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just use `return result`. Your second example will actually end up returning `None`, rather than the `result`. Here's a complete example demonstrating that:

```
from asyncio import coroutine
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def some_function():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(.5)
    return 5

@coroutine
def do_something():
    result = yield from some_function()
    return result


@coroutine
def do_something_else():
    future = asyncio.Future()
    result = yield from some_function()
    future.set_result(result)

@coroutine
def main():
    print((yield from do_something()))
    print((yield from do_something_else()))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
5
None
```

Note that they do become equivalent from the caller's perspective if you actually return the `Future` from `do_something_else`:

```
@coroutine
def do_something_else():
    future = asyncio.Future()
    result = yield from some_function()
    future.set_result(result)
    return future # Now yield from do_something_else() returns 5.
```

But it's just unnecessary extra work when you can just return `result` directly.

In the vast majority of cases, coroutines don't need to explicitly create a `Future` and call `set_result` on it at all. That pattern is occasionally useful, but you mostly see it in unit tests and frameworks, rather than in application code.

One interesting use of it is the implementation of `asyncio.sleep`:

```
@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    future = futures.Future(loop=loop)
    h = future._loop.call_later(delay, future.set_result, result)
    try:
        return (yield from future)
    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

Here a `Future` is created, the `set_result` method for that future is scheduled to be called after however long the caller wants to sleep, and then `yield from` is called on future, which will make the function wait for however long `delay` was, at which point `future.set_result(result)` is called, and the `yield from` call completes.

Comment: you may mention that (a) coroutine returning a value and (b) regular function returning future instance with value set up by `fut.set_result(value)` are equivalents from calling site. In both cases result can be achieved by `yield from f()` call.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Yes, I should have included that, since that's probably what the OP was trying to do with his second example. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, I mean **regular** function: https://gist.github.com/asvetlov/b33fa82618767b9ed82f

Comment: See https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/selector_events.py#L306 for example

Comment: Tangential question regarding your example - I'm trying to understand asyncio.  If I break "some_function" into two separate functions with different sleep times (the first sleeping longer than the second), and call the first function from do_something, and the second function from do_something_else, it seems the "yield from" statement blocks inside of the first some_function (called first with longer sleep time).  In other words, "do_something" always finishes before "do_something_else".  Is that the expected behavior?  Here's a pastebin of the modified code: http://pastebin.com/i20a70t3

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Yes, that's expected behavior, because you're calling `yield from do_something()` following by `yield from do_something_else()` inside of `main()`. `yield from coro` tells a coroutine to wait (without blocking the event loop - so other coroutines may run in parallel) for `coro` to complete before moving on. That means `main` will wait for `do_something` to finish before executing `do_something_else`. If you want both to run in parallel, call `yield from asyncio.gather(do_something(), do_something_else()` in `main()` instead.